# A question about using stripboard/perfboard instead of PCB for long duration

Tags: pcb, stripboard

I have made some analog interfaces by using perfboards or strip boards for a project which will run 6 months on a bridge but indoors and inside enclosures. The components were DIP package ICs and passive components. I also used conformal coating spray electrolube mostly at the solder sides.

I tested several times the circuits were working. But I am completely ignorant about life time or reliability of these boards. They will be powered and will process nonstop 6 months where I cannot have access.

Because of urgency, I didn't have time to spend drawing in a CAD program and obtain a PCB.

I'm not worried about not having ground plane and the circuits are working for low freq. applications.

I'm not expert in soldering and my biggest worry is that whether the solder joints would corrupt themselves after long time. But since the circuits were working I thought there is no cold solder.

Are there any problems using perfboard or strip board instead of PCB for such long durations? In other words is it a big risk or not to use stripboard or perfboard instead of PCB?

Comment: There have been working PCBs with cold solder joints causing problems months or years later. But making bad solder joints is possible using stripboards with unplated holes as well as PCBs with plated holes too. There are single side PCBs with unplated holes too. What about temperature and humidity within the indoor enclosure? There should be no condensation possible. Enclosures for outdor electronics are sometimes filled with dry nitrogen and sealed hermetically.

Comment: Is there something like epoxy to cover handmade circuits entirely?

Comment: Coatings made for PCBs may be used for stripboards too. It may be difficult to get them in very small packages.

Comment: If the board is running continuously in an enclosure, it probably won't be suffering from extreme temperature changes; I'd expect perfboard or stripboard builds to survive 6 months easily. What are the consequences if a board fails? Can you now layout, order, and assemble PCB versions to replace the prototypes, and have them installed as they become available?

Comment: @RussellBorogove  I can easily replicate them perfboard fr incase scenario to replace. But if there is not difference between PCB and perfboard in terms of stable duration I would think PCB way a bit time taking and risky since a small mistake in CAD will  delay time. I don't own a milling machine.

Comment: Vibration on the bridge ensures you have no confidence about any mechanical/electrical performance. Trust nothing.